# Zookeeper 3.5 and Curator 4.0: InterProcessMutex release() didn't delete lock path

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm using CuratorFramework 4.0.0 and Zookeper 3.5.4. 
I have this code snippet:

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryOneTime(1000);
client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnectionString, retryPolicy);
client.start();
String path = "/node/test_lock";
client.createContainers(path);
InterProcessSemaphoreMutex lock = new InterProcessSemaphoreMutex(client, path);
if (lock.acquire(3, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {                 
    LOGGER.debug(client.exists(lockPath) == null);
}
if (lock != null){
    lock.release();  // After I call this method,
                     // the "/node/test_lock" node still exists.
}
```

Using zookeeper version 3.5, the lock path should not be auto-deleted? I'm missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "parent" ZNodes for the lock recipes are created as [Container nodes](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.4-beta/zookeeperProgrammers.html#Container+Nodes). When a container node has no children remaining it is cleaned up by ZooKeeper. The default time check is 1 minute so you won't see the parent nodes removed until approx. 1 minute later (this value can be changed -- see here for details on [znode.container.checkIntervalMs](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.5.4-beta/zookeeperAdmin.html))